# Extracting date from string using regular expression

Tags: string, datetime, perl

I have a use case to extract date part from a string like this:

```
Job-2023-04-14.17.14.34
```

I need the output to be `2023-04-14`. I tried the code below:

```
# Extract the date part from the string using a regular expression.
my $date = $string =~ /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/;

# Check if the date part is defined.
if (defined $date) {
  # Print the date part.
  print "$date\n";
} else {
  # The date part is not defined.
  print "The string does not contain a valid date.\n";
}
```

But, it prints out 1.

Comment: `1` is the value of successful match. You did not capture the string, but you did match it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [capturing parentheses](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Capture-groups) in the regular expression, and use parentheses around `$date` to force list context:

```
my ($date) = $string =~ /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/;
```

Output:

```
2023-04-14
```

See also: [Perl Idioms Explained - @ary = $str =~ m/(stuff)/g](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=291543)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) could be to use a library capable of parsing dates, like `DateTime::Format::Strptime`:

```perl
#!/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $job='Job-2023-04-14.17.14.34';

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern => 'Job-%Y-%m-%d.%H.%M.%S'
);

my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime($job);

print "$dt\n";
```

Output:

```
2023-04-14T17:14:34
```